# How to commit changes inside tests and rollback them after each test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa

Here is a sample entity and a repository in a Spring Boot application. I'm trying to test it. I need to commit all changes inside each test and rollback them after the test is finished.

If I remove `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` then the changes not commited at all. And I don't get an exception when insert users with the same email and `emailIsUnique` is failed. If I add this annotation, then changes are commited and `emailIsUnique` is passed. But `userIsCreatedAndRead` is failed, because user John Doe is already created in `emailIsUnique` and not rollbacked.

How to fix it?

```
package com.example.springdata.entities;

import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalId;

@Entity(name = "Users")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(length = 100, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 100)
    private String login;

    @Column(length = 100, unique = true)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Column(length = 100)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(length = 100)
    private String lastName;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.springdata.repositories;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import com.example.springdata.entities.UserEntity;

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "users", collectionResourceRel = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, UUID> {

}
```

```
package com.example.springdata.repositories;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.springdata.entities.UserEntity;

import io.zonky.test.db.AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase;
import io.zonky.test.db.AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase.DatabaseProvider;

@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase(provider = DatabaseProvider.ZONKY)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
class UserRepositoryIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    void userIsCreatedAndRead() {
        UserEntity user = createEntity1();
        userRepository.save(user);

        assertThat(user.getId()).isNotNull();

        Optional<UserEntity> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(user.getId());
        assertThat(optionalUser).isPresent();

        optionalUser.ifPresent(foundUser -> assertThat(foundUser).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(user));
    }

    @Test
    void emailIsUnique() {
        UserEntity user1 = createEntity1();
        userRepository.save(user1);

        UserEntity user2 = createEntity2();
        user2.setEmail(user1.getEmail());
        assertThrows(DataIntegrityViolationException.class, () -> userRepository.save(user2));
    }

    private UserEntity createEntity1() {
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
        user.setLogin("john"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        user.setFirstName("John"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        user.setLastName("Doe"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        user.setEmail("john.doe@example.com"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        return user;
    }

    private UserEntity createEntity2() {
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
        user.setLogin("jane"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        user.setFirstName("Jane"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        user.setLastName("Smith"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        user.setEmail("jane.smith@example.com"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        return user;
    }

}
```

Comment: By default the test is already transactional (`@DataJpaTest` itself is `@Transactional` already) and should work as  you describe.

Comment: It works partly. `userIsCreatedAndRead` is passed, user saved and read, but I guess that it's read from a local cache. Record is not actually flushed to the DB. `emailIsUnique` is failed, because records are not actually inserted in the DB, and I don't get unique constraint violation.

Comment: If I add the following code `for (UserEntity u : userRepository.findAll()) { System.out.println(u); }` after a second user saving, then it forces records flush to the DB and I get `DataIntegrityViolationException` as expected. I guess I need a way to force records flush to DB in tests. Hmm... I could replace `CrudRepository` by `JpaRepository` and use `saveAndFlush()`. Maybe this solution is not so bad.

Comment: But maybe there is another solutions without `JpaRepository`?

Comment: You can inject the `TestEntityManager` and between `save` calls call `TestEntityManager.flush` instead of modifying your code to please the test.

Comment: Thanks! The following code works: `assertThrows(PersistenceException.class, () -> { userRepository.save(user2); testEntityManager.flush(); });` It's interesting that it throws another exception: `PersistenceException` instead of `DataIntegrityViolationException`. However, I think there is not much difference for testing.

Comment: Because you are calling the raw JPA API this way instead of through the repository and thus no exception translation will occur.